# Want to know about shared preference limit

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Is there any limit for shared preference, instead of sqlite,can I save in preference?

I saw in the documentation that max length is `8192`, that is preference elements size?

```
public static final int MAX_VALUE_LENGTH -
Maximum size in characters allowed for a preferences value.
Constant Value: 8192 (0x00002000)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size mentioned in the docs is the "maximum no of characters a value can have". Not the number of elements you can store.

Although there is no inherent limit to the number of items you can store - Retrieval and storage become very costly as the number of items increase.

SharedPreferences are meant to be used for global constants you might require throughout your app and not as a database replacement.

You cannot perform data manipulation and other SQLite operations on it.

So when the data is significant, Always go for a database.

Comment: So we can add so many key-pair values in shared preference, for particular key, value must be less than  8192 ie MAXLENGTH??

Comment: I have another doubt, regarding "SharedPreferences are meant to be used for global constants you might require throughout your app and not as a database replacement.", I saving login credentials in preference and also replacing value there? before replaccing i want to remove that key and then add value for that key?

Comment: if you store the same key again with a different value, it will automatically be replaced. You don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences are stored in /data/data/[package_name]/shared_prefs/[app name].xml. So there is no limit in storing in xml.

But if you want to handle large amount of data It will not be an efficient way to store in SharedPreferences. Better use database.